# Unable to replace Char(63) by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having some rows in table with some unusual character. When I use ascii() or unicode() for that character, it returns 63. But when I try this -

```
update MyTable
set MyColumn = replace(MyColumn,char(63),'')
```

it does not replace. The unusual character still exists after the replace function. Char(63) incidentally looks like a question mark.

For example my string is 'ddd#dd ddd' where # it's my unusual character and

```
select unicode('#')
```

return me 63.But this code

```
declare @str nvarchar(10) = 'ddd#dd ddd'
set @char = char(unicode('#'))
set @str = replace(@str,@char,'')
```

is working!

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Additional information:**

`select ascii('�')` returns 63, and so does `select ascii('?')`. Finally `select char(63)` returns `?` and not the diamond-question-mark.

When this character is pasted into Excel or a text editor, it looks like a space, but in an SQL Server Query window (and, apparently, here on StackOverflow as well), it looks like a diamond containing a question mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only does char(63) look like a '?', it is actually a '?'.

(As a simple test ensure you have numlock on your keyboard on, hold down the alt key andtype '63' into the number pad - you can all sorts of fun this way, try alt-205, then alt-206 and alt-205 again: ═╬═)

Its possible that the '?' you are seeing isn't a char(63) however, and more indicitive of a character that SQL Server doesn't know how to display.

What do you get when you run:

```
select ascii(substring('[yourstring]',[pos],1));
--or
select unicode(substring('[yourstring]',[pos],1));
```

Where `[yourstring]` is your string and `[pos]` is the position of your char in the string

**EDIT**

From your comment it seems like it is a question mark. Have you tried:

```
replace(MyColumn,'?','')
```

**EDIT2**

Out of interest, what does the following do for you:

```
replace(replace(MyColumn,char(146),''),char(63),'')
```

Comment: 146 - when I use type nvarchar, 63 when type is varchar

Comment: The result is the same as last time.

Comment: Then  I'm stumped max. Sorry.

Comment: I realise this is 8 years old, but I have this issue today. I copied a cell from Excel where the character looked like a space. Pasted into EditPlus text editor where it looked like a space. Copied from there into SQL Server 2016 Query Window where it looked like a solid (red, between string delimiters) diamond containing a (white) question mark inside it. `select ascii('�')` returns 63. So does `select ascii('?')`. Finally `select char(63)` returns `?` and not the diamond-question-mark. MSDN has an article "black diamond with question mark - MSDN - Microsoft" that I can't access.

Comment: PS. On saving in EditPlus, I got the message "This file contains characters which can be lost in the current encoding" - this might provide some clue as to how to resolve this issue in SQL? Following link talks about this EditPlus message: http://www.satya-weblog.com/2010/07/editplus-text-editor-encoding-support.html#thetrackbacks

Comment: @youcantryreachingme I couldn't resolve this issue by SQL Server so as I remember I created a simple .net console app for replacing all these characters and updating db then. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`char(63)` **is** a question mark. It sounds like these "unusual" characters are *displayed* as a question mark, but are not actually characters with char code `63`.

If this is the case, then removing occurrences of `char(63)` (aka `'?'`) will of course have no effect on these "unusual" characters.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you actually didn't have issues with literally CHAR(63), because that should be just a normal character and you should be able to properly work with it.

What I think happened is that, by mistake, an UTF character (for example, a cyrilic "А") was inserted into the table - and either your:

- columns setup,
- the SQL code,
- or the passed in parameters

were not prepared for that.
In this case, the sign might be visible to you as `?`, and its CHAR() function would actually give `63`, but you should really use the `NCHAR()` to figure out the real code of it.

> Let me give a specific example, that I had multiple times - issues
> with that Cyrilic "А", which looks identical to the Latin one, but has
> a unicode of `1040`.
>
> If you try to use the non-UTF CHAR function on that `1040` character,
> you would get a code `63`, which is not true (and is probably just an
> info about the first byte of multibyte character).
>
> Actually, run this to make the differences in my example obvious:
>
> ```
> SELECT NCHAR(65) AS Latin_A, NCHAR(1040) Cyrilic_A, ASCII(NCHAR(1040)) Latin_A_Code, UNICODE(NCHAR(1040)) Cyrilic_A_Code;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That empty string Which shows us '?' in substring.
Gives us Ascii value as 63.

It's a Zero Width space which gets appended if you copy data from ui and insert into the database.

To replace the data, you can use below query

```
**set MyColumn = replace(MyColumn,NCHAR(8203),'')**
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an older question, but I've run into this problem as well. I found the solution somewhere else on internet, but I thought it would be good to share it here as well. Have a good day.

Replace(YourString, nchar(65533) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, '')

Answer (score -1):

This should work as well:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
    SET [FieldName] =  SUBSTRING([FieldName], 2, LEN([FieldName])) 
    WHERE ASCII([FieldName]) = 63
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please expand on your solution to provide some context and explain how it answers the question.